# Alpha over compositor problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

[image]I'm trying to add a fog glow to the blue circles behind Susan using the compositor but so far not being able to make it, the fog glow is applied to all the image but no the blue circles or sometimes the blue circles appear on top of Susan lol
Thanks guys for your help, I'm new to the compositing world of Blender.
Blender file attached*

[image]

Comment: You should separate your image like this:
Monkey only - renderlayer #1 (foreground);
Circles only - renderlayer #2 (middleground);
Purple backing only - renderlayer #3 (background).

Don't forget to enable _transparent_ background in render tab.
For composing - plug circles to the _Glow_ node and then use _Alpha Over_ node to put monkey on top. Now put all of this on top of purple background with second _Alpha Over_

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks for your help, I enabled transparent background, setup the render layers the way you told me, plugged the circles to the Fog glow node, used the alpha over to put monkey on top and used an alpha over to put everything on top of the purple background but so far you can see the result in the new image that I re-uploaded here. I re-uploaded the Blend file with the new node setup that your advice, obviously I'm doing something wrong. thanks for your help    :)

Comment: Your mistake that you have a layer ("Main") which combines all in one: monkey, circles and background. In my first post I suggested you to put each of those to their individual layer.

Comment: Thanks Serge!! with your help I was able to make it! people like you make Blender the choice to go, what an awesome community.

Comment: Papasmurf7777, I'm glad you've worked it out!

Comment: Hey Serge, write your comment as answer! I vote it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Either separate by render layers or use a separate RGB in the compositor to create a mask that only select the blue.